inkscape rectangle with opaque background
I would like to place a rectangle on top of an existing drawing such that the drawing is covered by the rectangle completely. For example, in the following screenshot, I would like the rectangle to be opaque such that the letters below it are not visible. How can I do that?


Remove alpha from fill color : open fill and stroke panel (ctrl + shift + W), tab Fill and look for the last slider (with a A:) : set its value to 100.

Thank you, that did it!
